# Spring Security Login error Status 404 - /j_spring_security_check

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

This is the code for login system in Spring web mvc using spring security in eclipse.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/springsecurity-servlet.xml,
            WEB-INF/spring-sec.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springsecurity</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springsecurity</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

springsecurity-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="SpringSecurity" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/view/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

spring-sec.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            default-target-url="/index"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="j_username"
            password-parameter="j_password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="abcd" password="abcd" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

login.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

    <c:url value="j_spring_security_check" var="loginurl" />
    <form action="${loginurl}" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">Already have an account - Login</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <a href="${pageontext.request.contextPath }/forgotpassword">Forgot Password</a>
                </td>
            </tr>                                   
        </table>                                        
    </form>
    <span class="error">${loginMessage}</span>
```

LoginController.java:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView indexController(ModelMap model)
    {       
        return new ModelAndView("login", "welcomeMessage","Hello Guest! welcome to our site");
    }
}
```

Libraries used:

```
antlr-2.7.7
aopalliance-1.0
classmate-1.0.0
commons-beanutils-1.8.0
commons-digester-2.0
commons-fileupload-1.3.1
commons-io-2.4
commons-logging-1.2
dom4j-1.6.1
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final
hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final
hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final
jackson-annotations-2.5.0
jackson-core-2.5.0
jackson-databind-2.5.0
jandex-1.1.0.Final
javassist-3.18.1-GA
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0
javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6
jstl-1.2
mysql-connector-java-5.1.38
slf4j-api-1.7.6
spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-aspects-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-aspects-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-aspects-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-context-support-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-context-support-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-context-support-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-expression-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-expression-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-expression-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-instrument-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-instrument-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-instrument-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-jms-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-jms-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-jms-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-messaging-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-messaging-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-messaging-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-oxm-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-oxm-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-oxm-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-security-config-4.0.2.RELEASE
spring-security-core-4.0.2.RELEASE
spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE
spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-websocket-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-websocket-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-websocket-4.1.1.RELEASE
tiles-api-3.0.5
tiles-autotag-core-runtime-1.1.0
tiles-compat-3.0.5
tiles-core-3.0.5
tiles-el-3.0.5
tiles-extras-3.0.5
tiles-freemarker-3.0.5
tiles-jsp-3.0.5
tiles-mvel-3.0.5
tiles-ognl-3.0.5
tiles-request-api-1.0.6
tiles-request-freemarker-1.0.6
tiles-request-jsp-1.0.6
tiles-request-mustache-1.0.6
tiles-request-servlet-1.0.6
tiles-request-servlet-wildcard-1.0.6
tiles-request-velocity-1.0.6
tiles-servlet-3.0.5
tiles-template-3.0.5
tiles-velocity-3.0.5
validation-api-1.1.0.Final
xml-apis-1.0.b2
```

Error:

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
```

Eclipse project

```
https://jumpshare.com/v/LQ8M1Bn7lBYGEBE100cb
```

I am not getting the root cause of the problem. I tried hard but every time I am getting the same error. Is it library not compatible or some other error?

I am giving out the full project to test on your end, if you can find the error.

Thanks

Comment: what is 404? login page or after login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. I have to put

```
<csrf disabled="true" />
```

after `password-parameter="j_password" />` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the following Spring form taglib included on your page:

`<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>`)

If you use Springs `<form:form>` tag in your JSP instead of a standard HTML `<form>` it would add the (highly recommended) CSRF token automatically to your from.

This would be more secure and is good practice instead of disabling the feature.

Alternatively if you want to use a standard HTML `<form>` you can add the following hidden field and Spring Security will handle the rest:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```